# how to select categories for user generated content site?

Tags: content, navigation

On the site I'm building, users can create tutorials. I want the users to be able to create tutorials on as many  subjects as possible, but still have some preset categories. What's the best way to select these categories?

The reason I don't just let users add keywords, and use these for categorization, is because users gain experience points in a certain subject when their tutorial is liked by someone, and in a similar way the Stack Exchange network does, create communities around these subjects. I will give visiters the possibility to suggest new categories.

here are the categories that I'm thinking of at the moment:

- health
- gardening
- cooking
- technology
- science & math
- music
- visual art

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply use a dropdown list? In the form where they can put the text for their tutorial, you can put this list so they can choose between the category you want.

Comment: What I'm not looking for a way for users to choose cathegories, I'm looking for a way for me to find the best set of cathegories that cover a large number of subjects, without overwhealming users with choice.

Comment: Well, so you need a categorization system. That is not so easy to do. You need to extract some features from your data manually categorize them. After you can run a tool that will tell you in which category the post should be. This kind of system are statistical ones and so are not perfect. You can take a look to weka http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weka_(machine_learning)